# Mobile search results do not include entire search term

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, search

In mobile, I enter in the search field

```
[prolog] -[dcg] dcg
```

And I get the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D%20-%5Bdcg%5D%20dcg&__=1268531524), starting with a summary line:

> Search Results for dcg

No more. What I expect is a more detailed line including either the entire search term or at least an ellipsis.

When I search

```
[prolog] user:772868
```

I get even less. Simply:

> Search Results for

without any further specifics added. I could read the url to see what I searched for, alas, that is rather clumsy to get. Actually, I could also do "back"... With the same level of discomfort.

(There is no need to use a mobile device, clicking on "mobile" suffices)

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.